# Java 8 Stream run 1 function every index while another every n times

Tags: functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

Whats the best way to iterate over a Java 8 Stream such that I can perform one function for every element (forEach) while another for every 10 element. Every element using foreach displayed below. What function can I use .to intercept the eveyr nth element and perform the 2nd function call?

Sample code below : -

```
Stream<String> strings = Files.lines(path); //some stream

stream.forEach(s -> System::println)// every element but how can i perform
```

Answer (score 5):

Since [Guava version 22](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release22), you can use [`Streams.forEachPair`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#forEachPair-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) to accomplish what you want:

```
Stream<String> strings = Stream.of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");

Stream<Long> indexes = Stream.iterate(0L, i -> i + 1L);

Streams.forEachPair(strings, indexes, (s, i) -> {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Every 3rd element: " + s);
    } else {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
});
```

This creates an infinite stream of successive `Long` elements, starting from `0L`, and internally zips this stream with the `strings` stream. `Streams.forEachPair` accepts a `BiConsumer` that receives each pair of elements, one from each stream, and performs the action based on whether the index is the 3rd element or not.

You can abstract this more with the following helper method:

```
static <T> void forEachNthOrElse(
    Stream<T> stream, 
    int n, 
    Consumer<T> onNthElement,
    Consumer<T> onAnyOther) {

    Streams.forEachPair(
        stream, 
        Stream.iterate(0L, i -> i + 1),
        (t, i) -> {
            Consumer<T> action = i % n == 0 ? onNthElement : onAnyOther;
            action.accept(t);
        });
}
```

And, for the same example, you can use it as follows:

```
forEachNthOrElse(
    strings, 
    3, 
    s -> System.out.println("Every 3rd element: " + s), 
    System.out::println);
```

Note: I'm not sure if you need to execute the `System.out::println` action always, or only when the element is not the nth element. I implemented the `BiConsumer` to either execute one action or the other. If this is not the case (i.e. if you want to execute one action for the nth element and always execute the other action, even for the nth element), you should change the code accordingly.

Comment: new method, up!!

Answer (score 2):

Using Vavr(Javaslang) it can be fairly easy by using the provided `zipWithIndex` method:

```
 stream
    .zipWithIndex()
    .forEach(t2 -> {
        // something that runs for each element
        if (t2._2 % 10 == 0) {
            // something that runs every 10 elements
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since stream don't support `chunk`/`split` feature, but I have already answer in other question, so I paste it here. I wish it can helped you, for example:

```
Stream<String> strings = Files.lines(path); //some stream

//                  v--- skip the last chunk if the chunk size < 10?
split(strings, 10 , true).forEach((List<String> chunk)->{
//         each chunk size is 10 ---^ 

    //                        v--- Every element using foreach displayed  
    chunk.forEach(System.out::println);

    //                 v--- another for every 10 element.
    System.out.println(chunk);

});
```

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.Spliterators;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Stream;    
import static java.util.stream.StreamSupport.stream;


<T> Stream<List<T>> split(Stream<T> source,
                          int limit, boolean skipRemainingElements) {

    //variables just for printing purpose
    Spliterator<T> it = source.spliterator();
    long size = it.estimateSize();
    int c = it.characteristics();// characteristics

    return stream(new AbstractSpliterator<List<T>>(size, c) {
        private int thresholds = skipRemainingElements ? limit : 1;

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super List<T>> action) {
            List<T> each = new ArrayList<>(limit);

            while (each.size() < limit && it.tryAdvance(each::add)) ;

            if (each.size() < thresholds) return false;

            action.accept(each);
            return true;
        }

    }, false).onClose(source::close);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try writing a stateful method yourself without the use of any third party library, it could look something like this:

```
public <T> void foreachAndEveryNthDoSpecial( Stream<T> stream, Consumer<T> action, int n, Consumer<T> specialAction){
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    stream.forEach(t -> {
        if(count.incrementAndGet() % n == 0){
            specialAction.accept(t);
        }
        action.accept(t);
    });
}
```

Which then can be called like this:

```
foreachAndEveryNthDoSpecial(myStream, t -> yourAction, 10, t -> specialAction);
```